# "Internal Server Error" with wp_update_post

Tags: wp-update-post

I am coding a plugin for one of my sites which will toggle two pages statuses when a button is pressed. So when the ON button is pressed it will turn one page to draft while publishing the other, and vice versa with the OFF button.

The problem I am having is that when you press the button it bring you to a "Internal Server Error" page. You need to refresh that twice before it brings you to the page I want it to bring me to. How can I fix this.

My Code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Page Toggle
Description: Toggle page status
Version: 0.1
Author: Author
*/

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

function my_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Registration Switch', 'Registration', 'manage_options', 'registration.php', 'registration_admin_page', 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog', 6  );
}

if( isset( $_REQUEST['on'] )) {
    $my_post1 = array('ID' => 8,'post_status' => 'publish',);
    wp_update_post( $my_post1 );
    $my_post2 = array('ID' => 66,'post_status' => 'draft',); 
    wp_update_post( $my_post2 );
    echo "<h2>Registration is turned ON.</h2> <p><a href='#'>Go Back</a></p>";
}

if( isset( $_REQUEST['off'] )) {
    $my_post3 = array('ID' => 8,'post_status' => 'draft',); 
    wp_update_post( $my_post3 );
    $my_post4 = array('ID' => 66,'post_status' => 'publish',); 
    wp_update_post( $my_post4 );
    echo "<h2>Registration is turned OFF.</h2> <p><a href='#'>Go Back</a></p>";
}

function registration_admin_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Registration Information</h2>
        <h2>Toggle Registration</h2>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" name="on" value="Turn Registration On" class="button-secondary" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to enable registration?')" />
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="off" value="Turn Registration Off" class="button-secondary" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to disable registration?')" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I suspect it is because I call `wp_update_post` twice, although I am fairly noob with coding so don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are 2 issues in your code:

1. You were using PHP custom file name instead of `menu_slug`.
2. You were not using action and method attributes of form tag. When you were submitting form WordPress redirecting into admin.php?on=Turn+Registration+On which is not a valid page.

`add_submenu_page` function 4th parameter must be unique menu slug of your plugin not the custom PHP file.

Please have a look at the [`add_submenu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) function.

I have updated the code and tested. it working fine.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

function my_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Registration Switch', 'Registration', 'manage_options', 'page-toggle', 'registration_admin_page', 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog', 6  );
}

function registration_admin_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Registration Information</h2>
        <h2>Toggle Registration</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=page-toggle'); ?>" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="on" value="Turn Registration On" class="button-secondary" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to enable registration?')" />
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="off" value="Turn Registration Off" class="button-secondary" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to disable registration?')" />
        </form>
        <?php

        if( isset( $_REQUEST['off'] )) {
          $my_post3 = array('ID' => 90,'post_status' => 'draft');
          wp_update_post( $my_post3 );
          $my_post4 = array('ID' => 83,'post_status' => 'publish');
          wp_update_post( $my_post4 );
          echo "<h2>Registration is turned OFF.</h2>";
        } elseif (isset( $_REQUEST['on'] )) {
          $my_post1 = array('ID' => 90,'post_status' => 'publish');
          wp_update_post( $my_post1 );
          $my_post2 = array('ID' => 83,'post_status' => 'draft');
          wp_update_post( $my_post2 );
          echo "<h2>Registration is turned ON.</h2>>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am really noob when it comes to coding.

Comment: I am getting a "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." when I click on the buttons. Why is that?

Comment: Actually, I think I have figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have updated the code. Let me know if you are still getting the same error.  My mistake I were using incorrect menu slug. `admin.php?page=st-test` it must be `admin.php?page=page-toggle`

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out and fixed it. All is working well now! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Awesome, You're welcome :)